# Dynamodb Add or Update key in dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with the following structure:

```
'Items': [
   {'user_id': 'myuser',
    'owes_to': {
         'youruser': '10',
         'user3': '20'
       }
   }]
```

Is it possible in dynamodb to create a new user key in `owes_to` or if it already exists add to the value of that key?

In example in two calls:

1. Add 'user4' with value 20, It doesnt exist so create the user4 key with value 20)
2. Next time update user4 value 20 to 40, This time key already existed so add the 20 to the existing value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, update expression will be similar to this:

```
update_request = {
    Key={'user_id': ':id'},
    UpdateExpression='SET owes_to.#user_name = if_not_exists(owes_to.#user_name, :default_val) + :val',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#user_name': <your_user_name>
    }
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':id': 'myuser',
        ':val': <your_update_value>,
        ':default_val': 0
    }
}
```

Note the `if_not_exists(owes_to.#user_name, :default_val)` construction. It will take value of the user if it exists or take value specified in `:default_val` if it doesn't.
More about adding and updating map values in [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingNestedMapAttributes)